# Compile-errors: "creating array with negative size ('-0x00000000000000001')", "assignment of read-only location"

Tags: c, googlemock

Hi I'm new to GoogleMock but not new to mocking (I've python experience).

For a C-code based interface we want to use Googlemock. Up to compiling everything goes smoothly. No problems with defining the C-based code:
mock-header-file

```
#include "gmock/gmock.h"  
extern "C"
{
   #include "interface/interfacetype.h"
}
struct HELPER
{
   virtual ~HELPER() {}
   virtual int interface_func( ID_ENUM_TYPE id, MY_STRUCT_TYPE *params) = 0;
};
struct INTERFACE_MOCK : public HELPER
{
    MOCK_METHOD2( interface_func, int( ID_ENUM_TYPE id, MY_STRUCT_TYPE *params) );
};
extern INTERFACE_MOCK *mock_create_mock();
extern void mock_delete_mock();
```

mock-implementation:

```
#include mock.h
extern "C"
{
  #include "interface/interfacetype.h"
}
INTERFACE_MOCK *interface_2_mock = NULL;
extern "C"
{
   int interface_func( ID_ENUM_TYPE id, MY_STRUCT_TYPE *params )
   {
       return interface_2_mock->interface_func( id, params );
   }
}
INTERFACE_MOCK *mock_create_mock()
{
    if ( interface_2_mock == NULL )
    {
        interface_2_mock = new( INTERFACE_MOCK );
    }
    return interface_2_mock;
}
void mock_delete_mock()
{
    delete interface_2_mock;
}
```

MY_STRUCT_TYPE is as follows:

```
typedef struct my_struct_tag
{
    float value[196]
} MY_STRUCT_TYPE
```

unittest-code is as follows:

```
INTERFACE_MOCK *interface_2_mock;

class fixture : public ::testing::Test
{
   protected:
      virtual void SetUp()
      {
         interface_2_mock = mock_create_mock();
      }

      virtual void TearDown()
      {
         mock_delete_mock();
      }
};


TEST_F( fixture, test_case )
{
MY_STRUCT_TYPE params;
int result = 0;
for ( int i=0; i<196; i++)
{
    params.value[i] = 1.23;
}
// I'm only interested in checking that function is called,
            //  mocking the return-value and mocking 'params' which is an output-param
EXPECT_CALL( *interface_2_mock, interface_func( _, _ ) ) 
            .Times(2)
            .WillRepeatedly( DoAll( SetArgReferee<1>( &params ), return 0 ) ) );
// Call function_under_test which calls interface_func
result = function_under_test();
            ASSERT_EQ( 0, result ) << "Return-value " << result << " not as expected"
}
```

When compiling this all goes well until the EXPECT_CALL line is compiled. There we have the following error which we do not understand:

```
Rebuilding "<target>.oppsparc" on host "<host>" 

======== Finished "<target>.oppsparc" on host "<host>" ========
Sun native compile : test_my_test.cpp to test_my_test.oppsparc
In file included from ./gmock/gmock.h:65,
             from mock/interface_2_mock.hpp:33,
             from test_my_test.cpp:23:
./gmock/gmock-more-actions.h: In member function 'typename testing::internal::Function<F>::Result testing::SetArgRefereeActionP<k, value_type>::gmock_Impl<F>::gmock_PerformImpl(const typename testing::internal::Function<F>::ArgumentTuple&, arg0_type, arg1_type, arg2_type, arg3_type, arg4_type, arg5_type, arg6_type, arg7_type, arg8_type, arg9_type) const [with arg0_type =  ID_ENUM_TYPE , arg1_type = MY_STRUCT_TYPE*, arg2_type = testing::internal::ExcessiveArg, arg3_type = testing::internal::ExcessiveArg, arg4_type = testing::internal::ExcessiveArg, arg5_type = testing::internal::ExcessiveArg, arg6_type = testing::internal::ExcessiveArg, arg7_type = testing::internal::ExcessiveArg, arg8_type = testing::internal::ExcessiveArg, arg9_type = testing::internal::ExcessiveArg, F = void( ID_ENUM_TYPE , MY_STRUCT_TYPE*), int k = 1, value_type = MY_STRUCT_TYPE*]':
./gmock/gmock-generated-actions.h:664:   instantiated from 'static Result testing::internal::ActionHelper<Result, Impl>::Perform(Impl*, const std::tr1::tuple<_U1, _U2>&) [with A0 = ID_ENUM_TYPE , A1 =MY_STRUCT_TYPE*, Result = void, Impl = testing::SetArgRefereeActionP<1, MY_STRUCT_TYPE*>::gmock_Impl<void( ID_ENUM_TYPE ,MY_STRUCT_TYPE*)>]'
./gmock/gmock-more-actions.h:170:   instantiated from 'typename testing::internal::Function<F>::Result testing::SetArgRefereeActionP<k, value_type>::gmock_Impl<F>::Perform(const typename testing::internal::Function<F>::ArgumentTuple&) [with F = void( ID_ENUM_TYPE , MY_STRUCT_TYPE*), int k = 1, value_type = MY_STRUCT_TYPE*]'
test_my_test.cpp:251:   instantiated from here
./gmock/gmock-more-actions.h:175: error: creating array with negative size ('-0x00000000000000001')
./gmock/gmock-more-actions.h:177: error: assignment of read-only location 'std::tr1::get [with int __i = 1, _Elements = ID_ENUM_TYPE, MY_STRUCT_TYPE*](((const std::tr1::tuple<ID_ENUM_TYPE, MY_STRUCT_TYPE*>&)((const std::tr1::tuple<ID_ENUM_TYPE, MY_STRUCT_TYPE*>*)args)))'
*** Error code 1
========================================================

Aborting...
```

Can you help us?

/* edit */ I saw that I left out the fixture

Comment: Most likely the "creating array with negative size" comes from a "poor man's static assert", i.e somewhere in the program the programmer has written a compile time assertion to ensure that some values are correct, and when it fails you get the mentioned error.

Comment: @Lundin: Thanx for your reply, but it turned out that passing-by-reference and passing-by-pointer-reference should not be confused. As I explained below I should have used SetArgPointee i.s.o. SetArgReferee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This time I found the answer. Instead of SetArgReferee<1>( &params ), I've should have used SetArgPointee<1>( params )